# Compile TypeScript for Node.js with all features

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, ecmascript-6

If I compile TypeScript for Node.js with

```
tsc --module commonjs --target ES5
```

I can't use `async`/`await` or generators because `tsc` doesn't know how to compile it to ES5.

That can be fixed if I compile TypeScript for Node.js with

```
tsc --module commonjs --target ES6
```

but then I can't use default parameters or destructuring assignment, because Node.js doesn't support them. `tsc` knows how to compile those to ES5, but it only does it if you actually target ES5.

How can I target Node.js with support for all of TypeScript's features?

Comment: You could target ES6 and then use babeljs to compile that for ES5.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but it complicates things. I was hoping `tsc` was the only build tool I needed. I mean, internally it does everything it needs to target Node.js's combination of features, but there doesn't seem to be an option for it. :(

Comment: Not an answer, but I would also encourage looking at fleshing out your pipeline. Setting up a gulpfile took me all of 20 minutes and does what I need (tsc-> browserify -> header). I thought it would be annoying, turns out it was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with running your ES6 compiled code in latest node.js (v5.x). To enable the particular ES6 featuresthat are not enabled by default you should use --harmony flags. Like this for example:

> node --harmony-destructuring

For the complete list of possible harmony features to play with - run:

> node --v8-options | grep harmony